# Winerror 3 for text extraction

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

How can I fix this?

```
File "C:\Users\steve\Desktop\my_code.py", line 15, in extract_text_from_images
    image_files = [os.path.join(folder_path, file) for file in os.listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"))]
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\Imagesfortextextraction'
```

I tried fixing the error by naming the folder where the images are supposed to be stored, but no luck.

Comment: As the error is indicating, `os.listdir` can't seem to find `folder_path` which has value `"C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\Imagesfortextextraction"`. Try replacing `folder_path` with a hardcoded absolute path to the expected folder.

Comment: can you please explain how should i change the folder path?i am new to coding

Comment: In your code for os.listdir, you have a variable `folder_path`, right? Instead of using that variable, put in the absolute path to the expected folder. I don't know what the expected folder is, you seem to think it is `"C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\Imagesfortextextraction"` but Windows is saying it doesn't exist. The point here is to make it work with a hardcoded path, then need to apply that path to the variable.

Comment: can i show you my code? I've tried everything i can, i bought book for python and im having trouble understanding it.

Comment: well now its working but the issue is its not saving in the folder indicated i dont know why, thanks for helping im new at coding.

Comment: this what my command prompt window is displaying this (but i cant find the extracted text in any of my notepad files) C:\Users\steve\Desktop>my_code.py
Enter a command: extract
Text extraction from all images completed.
Enter a command: robot
Hello, how may I assist you?
Enter a command: